# При столкновении с вертикальным объектом в прыжке, меняется анимация Jump на Idle

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Есть персонаж с анимацией Run, Jump и Idle. Есть вертикальная стена и платформа.
На блоках стоит скрипт, что когда к ним прикасаешься персонаж переходит в анимацию Idle. Если во время прыжка дотронуться до стены или вертикальной части платформы то персоныж переходит из анимации Jump в Idle.

[image: Остановка анимации]
Как сделать так чтобы при прикосновении с ними анимация не менялась, но и в тоже время если встать на платформу анимация сменилась.

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upravlenie : MonoBehaviour {

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    public float verticalImpulse;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool isGrounded;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    bool Fliped = false;
    bool Running = false;

    private Animator animator;

    private CharState State
    {
        get { return (CharState)animator.GetInteger("State"); }
        set { animator.SetInteger("State", (int)value); }
    }

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

    public void LeftButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        Running = true;
        if (Fliped == false) 
            Flip(); 
            Fliped = true; 
    }

    public void RightButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        Running = true;
        if (Fliped == true) 
            Flip(); 
            Fliped = false; 
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Running = false;
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void A_Idle()
    {
        State = CharState.Idle;
    }

    public void OnClickJump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpulse), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            State = CharState.Jump;
            isGrounded = false;
            Running = false;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isGrounded && Running == true)
            State = CharState.Run;
        if (isGrounded && Running == false)
            State = CharState.Idle;

        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            isGrounded = true;
    }

}

public enum CharState
{
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

P.S Использую компонент event trigger на кнопках.

Comment: `На блоках стоит скрипт, что когда к ним прикасаешься персонаж переходит в анимацию Idle` - зачем на них такой скрипт? блоки не должны управлять состоянием персонажа. Ты лучше при приземлении персонажа проверяй тег элемента, если это tag=platform и скорость персонажа = 0, то переходить в Idle

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сделал вот так: 
`void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isGrounded && Running == true)
            State = CharState.Run;
        if (gameObject.tag == "Ground" && speedX == 0)
            State = CharState.Idle;
        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            isGrounded = true;
    }`

теперь не переключается на анимацию Idle после прыжка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ещё этот способ не поможет тем, что если достать головой до платформы анимация переключиться

Comment: я же писал, что  при приземлении персонажа проверяй тег элемента, если это tag=platform и скорость персонажа = 0. у тебя я этого не наблюдаю

Comment: `ещё этот способ не поможет тем, что если достать головой до платформы анимация переключиться` - поэтому обычно у персонажей **в ногах** располагают пустой GameObject с триггером и неким радиусом `CircleCollider2D`, который и сообщает о том приземлился он или нет.

Comment: Хотя даже при запрыгивании на платформу скорость не обязательно проверять. но на тег стоит проверить

Comment: кстати, в `FixedUpdate` надо бы работать с физикой, для простой логики и вычислений надо использовать `Update`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне сменить на Update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов уйма

1. Кидать boxcast/raycast на маленькое расстояние от чуть выше до чуть ниже ног
2. Сделать триггер под ногами
3. Брать точку коллизии и сверять по расстоянию с точкой в районе ног.
4. Ну совсем для "психов" поиграться нормалью коллизии и вектор Up персонажа. Если направление или угол соответствует( разное направление/ угол 180).
5. Можно еще напридумывать...

В основе всего лежит то самое маленькое значение/ делта. Даже с углом например +-1 градус.
Возможные оптимизации, включать эти проверки только после прыжка/начала падения. Маленькое значение варьировать в зависимости от скорости.
Минусы:

1. Визуально сложно настроить особенно boxcast.
2. Лишний мусор в иерархии персонажа+ зависимость от OnTriggerEnter и тому подобного.
3. Дороже в плане коллизии, также визуально сложнее, ограничение сферой, ну если конечно свою проверку пересечения сторон прямоугольника не писать.
4. Ну тут без комментариев...

P.s.  Верно подмечено в комментариях убери FixedUpdate.
P.s.s. я бы остановился на 1ом варианте